# open a window or an image rapidly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am  write a code with JavaScript.
It's should be like a desktop when click on an icon should open rapidly like this picture I send it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWnQL.jpg)
my problem is that when I click on icons It's just open one time.
for example click on first pic from top to see it
here is my code.

```js
let pc = document.getElementById('pc')
let folder = document.getElementById('folder')
let bin = document.getElementById('bin')
let pcwindow = document.getElementById('pcwindow')
let b1 = document.getElementById('b1')


for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    pc.addEventListener("click", () => {

        pcwindow.style.display = "block"


    })
}
b1.addEventListener("click", () => {

    pcwindow.style.display = "none"

})
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url(img/150-1509609_hd-abstract-wallpaper-neon-smoke-71-images-colorful.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.folder {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.pc {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.bin {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.pcwindow {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
}

#b1 {
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="pc">
        <img id="pc" class="pc" src="content/img/Gabriel-Leblanc-Historic-Mac-Mac.512.png" alt="">

    </div>

    <div id="folder" class="folder">
        <img class="folder" src="content/img/folder.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="bin" class="bin">
        <img class="bin" src="content/img/icons8-recycle-bin-48.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="pcwindow" class="pcwindow">
        <input id="b1" type="button">
    </div>
    <script src="content/script.js"></script>
```

code.

Comment: `document.getElementById('pc')` returns only one element. If you have more than one element with `id='pc'`, that is the issue. Use a class instead.

Comment: I have one element I need a some thing like loop to when click again on first pic window should open again on previous window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually this:
adding
`position: absolute;`
to all of windows css and then add     `name of window.style.top = "50px" name of window.style.left = "100px"` to eache window in script.